# Consolidating Multiple Google sheets using query function

Tags: function, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

[DATA1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XKeIK-8BH_JVZEWLsTWlyjgmvkymEvPPlln9M0dOCDc/edit#gid=1375664043)

I have this job data profiles which I want to consolidate, I used Query Function to join the datasheets, but column C & D are incorrect. Can someone please tell me where is the formula wrong. 
I tried modifying my formula to:

```
={FILTER('JOB1'!A1:J, LEN('JOB1'!A1:A) > 0);FILTER('JOB2'!A2:J, LEN('JOB2'!A2:A) > 0);FILTER('JOB3'!A2:J, LEN('JOB3'!A2:A) > 0)}
```

This is giving the same error.

Comment: seems like a formatting thing. Can you select those column(s) and do `Format > Number > Automatic` and see how it goes...

Comment: @rockinfreakshow these are % and dates column, if I change them to automatic they might loose the infomation

Comment: I have opened the sheet to edit for everyone.

Comment: +formatting fixed

Comment: thank you, I want another help, are you available?

Comment: @Lily You is not accessible. Please make it public.